# Batch Scripting .. what means: <name>.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME

Tags: batch-file, command, escaping, character

So i have a Batch Script which i got trough a task at work, there is an error inside the script which i lokated at the following position of the code

```
REM Install service  
echo register Service...
%INSTALL_PATH%<name_of_exe>.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%   #error here
echo successfully installed %SERVICE_NAME%.
```

So as squashman told after starting of an .exe there follow parameters. So to this point it is clear,

```
//IS//%SERVICE_NAME%    #is parameter
```

So i want to know if  //IS// is some kind of "batch-magic". So it is not some kind of crazy Windows Path since there are "/" not "\". So my it is some kind of character-escaping?

Comment: Sure would like to know where you got that example from. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: its some code from my company and they register a service with this command so i will update the code above

Comment: Ask your I.T. people.  I have no idea what executable you are running. Whatever comes after the executable name is input to the executable.  Did you Google search for the name of the executable you are using?

Comment: no reason to be harsch, i just thought it would be some kind of batch-magic where someone has a fast response .. so i upated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found it out.

There is a Programm called Procrun from ApacheCommons with the following description

***Procrun*** is a set of applications that allow Windows users to wrap (mostly) Java applications (e.g. Tomcat) as a Windows service.
The service can be set to automatically start when the machine boots and will continue to run with no user logged onto the machine.

So now the Problem line was easy to understand since the .exe belongs to *procrun*.

```
   <name>.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%   # //IS - install service 
                                     # //%SERVICE_NAME% - the name
```